# Set .desktop file as allow launching on Ubuntu 22.04 terminal?

Tags: gnome, permissions, 22.04, .desktop

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
GNOME Shell 42.9

I am working on a shell script to cp .desktop files to Desktop.
And I run into issues when I need set all the .dekstop files to be allow launching in the script. I can right-click each file and select allow launching, but this would be very tedious if doing on multiple .desktop files.

I've set chmod +x file.desktop

I've tried gio set file.desktop metadata::trusted true and get error gio: Setting attribute metadata::trusted not supported

looking at gio info ./file.desktop, there is no trusted line.

```
display name: file.desktop
edit name: file.desktop
name: file.desktop
type: regular
size:  191
uri: file:///home/user/Desktop/file.desktop
local path: /home/user/Desktop/file.desktop
unix mount: /dev/nvme0n1p2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
attributes:
  standard::type: 1
  standard::name: file.desktop
  standard::display-name: file.desktop
  standard::edit-name: file.desktop
  standard::copy-name: file.desktop
  standard::icon: application-x-desktop, text-x-generic, application-x-desktop-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic
  standard::content-type: application/x-desktop
  standard::fast-content-type: application/x-desktop
  standard::size: 191
  standard::allocated-size: 4096
  standard::symbolic-icon: application-x-desktop-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic, application-x-desktop, text-x-generic
  etag::value: 1709569720:492963
  id::file: l66308:37929684
  id::filesystem: l66308
  access::can-read: TRUE
  access::can-write: TRUE
  access::can-execute: FALSE
  access::can-delete: TRUE
  access::can-trash: TRUE
  access::can-rename: TRUE
  time::modified: 1709569720
  time::modified-usec: 492963
  time::access: 1709569720
  time::access-usec: 512963
  time::changed: 1709569720
  time::changed-usec: 492963
  unix::device: 66308
  unix::inode: 37929684
  unix::mode: 33188
  unix::nlink: 1
  unix::uid: 1000
  unix::gid: 1000
  unix::rdev: 0
  unix::block-size: 4096
  unix::blocks: 8
  owner::user: user
  owner::user-real: user
  owner::group: user
```

I've tried changing to root user owned and still can't get it to work.

One thing I did notice, was if I changed the file to allow launching in the right-click menu, nothing changes in the gio info, but if I rm file and try to cp it back to Desktop, it keeps the property to allow launching. So, I think there is a log that keeps track of this.

Thanks to anyone who figures this out.